# referential integrity in 2 tables in oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle10g

I have a table in Oracle, the table is something like:

```
create table serv (
ser number(7),
mno number(4), 
cp number(4),
primary key (ser, mno, cp)
);
```

And other table, and is like:

```
create table ftp (
mno number(4),
cp number(4),
ftp varchar2(9),
ser number(7),
constraint fk_prueba
  foreign key (mno, ser,cp)
  references serv (mno, ser,cp)
);
```

And I am trying to insert into the serv table the following values:

```
insert into serv values(1,2,3);
```

Now I am inserting into ftp table the values:

```
insert into ftp values (1,2,'hola',null);
insert into ftp values (1,5,'hola',null);
insert into ftp values (1,9,'hola',null);
```

And the problem is that I can insert the values in FTP, and the values can not be inserted, because in serv I have the mno 2, and I am inserting a mno into ftp that does not exist in serv.

I need insert values in ftp, that exist in serv.

Who can help?

Thanks

Comment: That's a very good point in fact. In Oracle, this is limitation or property, not sure. I don't know the exact reason but a composite foreign key is never checked for parent key in master table if one or more of the column of key in the child table is inserted as null.

Answer (score 1):

- you are creating composite primary key and referencing it by a child table. So you are creating relation between two table based on  combination ser, mno, cp . Only that combination is referred from patent table..it wont treat each value seperately
- so, relate two table by creating referential integrity on column ser and composite ref.int on mno & cp

Answer (score 0):

This is how Foreign Key works in Oracle. Use this to overcome the issue

```
 NOT NULL references serv (mno, ser,cp)
```